# How can I fix c# masked textbox right-to-left input behaviour?

Tags: c#, winforms, right-to-left, maskedtextbox, maskedinput

I use `WinForms` masked textbox to input time in the format of `hh:mm:ss`. My mask for this is `99:99:99`, and I use `right-to-left` input mode.

The problem is, when I type `123` into it, I expect it to input `1:23`, but it does this instead: `__:12:3_` (so the value is `12:3x`, and it replaces x with the next value that is typed).

What can I do to make it just push text to the left instead of copying the whole `ss` block to `mm`?

**Edit:** Here's a clarification:
My client needs to input time values in such a way that when he types:
`12[Enter]` it is accepted as 12 seconds
`123[Enter]` is 1 minute, 23 seconds
`1234[Enter]` would be 12 minutes, 34 seconds
`12345[Enter]` would be 1 hour, 23 minutes, 45 seconds, and so on...

The problem is that when `123` is typed into a masked textbox, it moves `12` to the `minutes` field, instead of just the `1`, and only the `3` is left inside the `seconds` field.

**Edit 2:** As anyone who has worked with the masked textbox knows, setting the TextAlign to Right doesn't work the way you'd expect it to, like in any normal text editor. Instead, it just places the whole mask on the right side of the control, but the values are still inserted the same way as when the TextAligh is Left.
This is why I tried using RightToLeft.

Comment: There are limitations in using the maskedtextbox control and this is one of them. You may want to look at this [MSDN Forum Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b5b35b2b-4705-4a16-b536-65e5def3ebe1/text-entry-from-right-to-left?forum=winformsdesigner) which I found in this [websearch](http://www.bing.com/search?q=winforms+maskedtextbox+enter+right+to+left&qs=SC&sk=SC1&pq=winforms+masked+&sc=5-16&sp=2&FORM=QBLH&cvid=0daf52b549d6432a8fa75b5bd1101f60&ghc=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want seems to be near impossible.  How will the maskedtextbox know if you mean 1 digit to or 2 digits to apply to the first field that you type, unless you type the colon to show the separation?

I think for what you seem to want a`DateTimePicker` with a custom format of `hh:mm:ss` would work better.  The input automatically starts at the `hours` field. The user can type 1 digit  or 2 digits and then the colon and the input will automatically move to the next field.  You also have the option of UpDown buttons that the user can click on to change the highlighted field.

By near impossible, I meant with native behavior.  By creating a custom textbox that inherits from textbox you can do what you want:

```
public class TimeTextBox : TextBox
{
    public TimeTextBox()
    {
        this.KeyPress += TimeTextBox_KeyPress;
    }
    public DateTime timeValue = new DateTime();
    private void TimeTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        if(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            Text += e.KeyChar;
            SelectionStart = Text.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong input");
            return;
        }
        FixText();
        if(Text.Length > 3  && !DateTime.TryParse(Text, out timeValue))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong input");
            Text = Text.Remove(Text.Length - 1);
            FixText();
            timeValue = DateTime.Parse(Text);
        }
    }
    private void FixText()
    {
        Text = Text.Replace(":", "");
        for(int i = Text.Length - 3; i > -1; i -= 2)
        {
            Text = Text.Insert(i + 1, ":");
            SelectionStart = Text.Length;

        }
    }
}
```

This will format and validate the input always counting from the right and inserting colons every 2 characters.  There's simple validation, but it hasn't been tested for all scenarios.

Comment: I don't see why it would be impossible. All it needs to do is move all previous digits one place to the left every time a new digit is typed in (like ordinary textbox does when TextAlign is Right).
As for the DateTimePicker, that is what I originally used, but my client finds it too cumbersome since he needs to input values very quickly, and beginning with seconds.

Comment: @Gnosa - I expanded my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple text box and break the string as per this logic. I have only shown you for minutes and seconds you can extend it to hours following the code.

```
int seconds, minutes;
if (textBox1.Text.Length == 1 || textBox1.Text.Length == 2)
{
    seconds = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
}
else if (textBox1.Text.Length == 3)
{
    seconds = int.Parse(textBox1.Text.Substring(1, 2));
    minutes = int.Parse(textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1));
}
else if (textbox1.Text.Length == 4)
{
    seconds = int.Parse(textBox1.Text.Substring(2, 2));
    minutes = int.Parse(textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't understand the question, I'm afraid. I do use RightToLeft, and it misbehaves, as I've described above.

Comment: It is not misbehaving when you use RightToLeft it is supposed to be like that.

The RightToLeft property is used for international applications where the language is written from right to left, such as Hebrew or Arabic. When this property is set to RightToLeft. Yes, control elements that include text are displayed from right to left.

Comment: What i meant to say is it doesn't behave the way I need it to behave. Do you know any way to fix that?

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand how exactly do you want it to behave?

Comment: I added a clarification to the question.

Comment: I think you will have to use a simple text box and then obtain the number by int.Parse() and use calculations to store the values. I will provide you with some. Check my edit in a while.